# Migrate YUI 2 to YUI 3

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3

What is the migration path for upgrading the Yahoo JS & CSS libraries from version 2 to version 3?

Specifically: CSS & fonts, button, TabView.

Any pointers to further information about issues encountered, tips to make it easier, etc would be greatly appreciated.

Different Google searches (e.g. [upgrading yui2](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=upgrading+yui3), [migrating yui2](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=upgrading+yui3)) didn't turn up much on this.

Answer (score 3):

CSS Fonts is pretty much 1:1 in my experience. TabView works differently but functionality wise should be equivalent.

Here's a great overview recently posted to the YUI blog that gives you a pretty thorough overview of each component in 2 vs 3.

http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/11/05/a-status-check-on-the-yui-2-to-3-transition/

Comment: The link above is now dead.

Comment: [Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20200809104156/http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/11/05/a-status-check-on-the-yui-2-to-3-transition/) has it.